# Porque o DO WHILE pulou o número 15 desse loop

Tags: java, loop

Estava olhando uma prova do Corpo auxiliar de Praças da marinha, quando me deparei com essa pergunta:

> ANALISE O CÒDIGO JAVA:

```
public class DoWhileProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numero = 10;
        do{
            if(numero % 5 !=0)
                System.out.printf("%d ", numero);
                numero++;
            
        }while(numero<=16);
    }
}
```

> QUAL O RESULTADO DESSE CÓDIGO?

O resultado do código é `11 12 13 14 16`.

Eu gostaria de saber o porquê.

Comment: `(numero % 5 !=0)` qualquer número entre 10 e 16 cujo resto da divisão por `5` não seja `0`, será imprimido na tela, ou seja, apenas o número 47 do meu pé que eu não acho em loja nenhuma.

Comment: é que 15 é um múltiplo de 5. essa  condição foi   **resto da divisão de  um número por 5 é diferente de 0** todos os números que não são múltiplos de 5 vai ser true

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A lógica deste trecho de código está sob as divisões exatas do número 5, exemplo: 5/5 = 1, 10/5 = 2 e 15/5 = 3. Observe que nestes casos não "sobra" um valor da divisão, tendo o **resto** = **"0"**.

Em situações onde a divisão não é exata, exemplo: 11/5, 12/5 e 13/5, não haverá a divisão por números inteiros, fazendo com que haja um valor não divisível. No caso da divisão "11%5" será feito o seguinte cálculo: **11 - (5 * 2) = 1**. O valor **"1"** é o resto desta divisão.

Estando ciente disso, observe a expressão booleana apontada no "IF", que visa apresentar apenas os números onde a divisão por **"numero % 5"** possui o resultado diferente de zero, sendo estes os valores: 11 12 13 14 16.

Segue abaixo a implementação de uma classe que facilita a compreensão da lógica por trás deste algoritmo:

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      int numero    = 10;
            do {
                int resultado = numero % 5;
                System.out.println("A divisão " + numero + " % 5 resulta em " + resultado + ".\nO valor "  + resultado + " é diferente de 0?");
                if (resultado != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Verdadeiro.");
                    System.out.printf("Saída: %d \n \n", numero);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Falso.  \n");
                }
                numero++;
            } while (numero <= 16);
        }
}
```

Para executar o código de forma rápida eu utilizei um compilador online: https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/

Em caso de dúvidas sobre o operador "%", acesse: [https://www.devmedia.com.br/java-operadores-de-atribuicao-aritmeticos-relacionais-e-logicos/38289#:~:text=Os%20operadores%20de%20atribui%C3%A7%C3%A3o%2C%20aritm%C3%A9ticos,compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20s%C3%A3o%20apenas%20alguns%20exemplos](https://www.devmedia.com.br/java-operadores-de-atribuicao-aritmeticos-relacionais-e-logicos/38289#:%7E:text=Os%20operadores%20de%20atribui%C3%A7%C3%A3o%2C%20aritm%C3%A9ticos,compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20s%C3%A3o%20apenas%20alguns%20exemplos).

Espero ter ajudado, em caso de dúvidas estou aqui :)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, as vezes são as coisa mais simples que me confundem.